# Две activity и один xml

Tags: android

Можно ли в Android Studio сделать так, чтобы два файла(.kt или .java) с кодом работали на одном layout. Просто если местами менять их в файле манифеста, то код каждого файла работает, но по отдельности. В обоих файлах содержаться кнопки, прогресс бар и т.д

Comment: скажите пожалуйста, ваши активити выполняют одинаковые функции, или хотя-бы приблизительно одинаковые? просто стоит задуматься о том чтобы провести слияние этих двух классов в один, просто добавить несколько условных операторов.

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko проблема в том, что я не один проект делаю и надо делать слияние частей. Моя часть отвечает за подключение и передачу данных по bluetooth, есть кнопка подключения и настроек и надо мою часть совместить с графическим редактором коллеги, у которого тоже кнопки есть. Мой класс получился большим, так что соединить в один класс проблематично.

Comment: я вас понял, чисто гипотетически можете попробовать использовать одну и ту же разметку при вызове классов, просто я не очень знаком с файлами `kt`, вероятнее всего будут ошибки, у меня почему-то есть желание посоветовать вам использовать фрагменты, но я не уверен что мой совет верный.

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko что вы имеете ввиду под разметкой? Проблема вся в том, что само приложение не видит кода второго файла. А фрагменты не получится использовать, потому, что у коллеги есть кнопка, которая вызывает один из моих методов и при нажатии кнопки крашится приложение

Comment: в функции `onCreate` есть метод `setContentView` в котором вы указываете файл разметки. А почему крашится приложение известно, может попытаться решить эту проблему, и проблема с использованием одного layout решится тоже?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko это я уже делал setContentView(R.layout.activity_designer), где activity_designer и есть layout на котором все происходит

Comment: а может вынести методы из вашего класса в отдельный класс, чтобы ваш коллега к отдельному классу обращался?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko в том и проблема, что метод этот завязан на других методах, тогда придется пол класса перемещать. Решение где-то на поверхности, надо что-то изменить в файле манифеста

Comment: а почему вы решили что в файле манифеста дело?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko потому что, когда меняю строчку android:name=".DesignerActivity" на android:name=".BluetoothActivity", то моя часть начинает работать, а коллеги нет

Comment: это наименования классов я так понимаю? просто я не думаю что можно указать два имени в манифесте, но я могу ошибаться

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko  Видимо да, надо просто как-то добавить свой класс, пробовал ниже прописать по этому примеру, но не помогло https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870202/how-to-add-activity-to-manifest-xml-in-right-way

Comment: ну в вашем примере у человека две полноценные активити, у него есть два отдельных класса, и походу две разметки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Два класса `Activity` могут использовать один файл xml. Но нужно понимать, что этот файл никак не связывает экземпляры активностей - он лишь описывает макет, по которому каждая активность создаст свой набор вью-элементов.

Так же нужно понимать, что две активности не могут жить одновременно и уж тем более обращаться к вью-элементам и методам друг друга.
Одна активность может запустить другую методами [`startActivity(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)) и [`startActivityForResult(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) и передать в неё какие-то данные через `Intent`, а при запуске вторым вариантом получить какие-то данные обратно.

Но если Вам нужно совместить коды двух классов для использования в одном экране приложения - это возможно - сделав один наследником другого. Тогда наследник получит всё что есть у родителя, за исключением доступа к приватным членам.

Comment: Сделал наследование, перед этим сделав родительский класс абстрактным. Всем спасибо!

Comment: И еще onCreate надо удалить в классе наследника

Comment: Удалять сам метод не обязательно, но лишний, дублирующий код из него убрать нужно и обязательно вызвать `super.onCreate(...);` иначе код родительского метода не выполнится - а для активностей это обязательное условие.

Comment: Все верно, пришлось onCreate вернуть, так как половина кнопок коллеги перестала работать, я в onCreate удалил только setContentView(R.layout.activity_designer) и все заработало)